# error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]|

Tags: c, gcc, glibc

I get this if I try to compile with one of C standards:

`-std=c99`, `-std=c11` or `-std=c17` .

If I remove them compiles fine or if I use `-std=gnuXX` works as well

Why is happening that, because I just can't fix it.

program.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT "5555"
#define BACKLOG 5

int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res );
int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res );
int accept_fd( struct sockaddr_storage *their_addr, int *sockfd );
int list_fd( int *sockfd );
int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd );
ssize_t write_fd( const char *const msg, int *new_fd );

int main(void){
    const char *msg = "Hello socket World!\n";
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    struct addrinfo server, *res;
    int sockfd, new_fd;

    /* create a socket: */
    getAdr_fd( server, &res );
    sockfd = create_fd( &res );

    /* Bind */
    bind_fd( &res, &sockfd );

    /* Listen */
    list_fd( &sockfd );

    /* Accept connection: */
    new_fd = accept_fd( &their_addr, &sockfd );

    /* Write */
    write_fd( msg, &new_fd );

    /* close: */
    close(sockfd);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
 }

 int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res ){
    int getfd;

    /* Create address structs with getaddrinfo(): */

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);
    server.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
    server.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    server.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // fill in my IP for me

    getfd = getaddrinfo( NULL, PORT, &server, res);
    if (getfd != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror( getfd ));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
        printf("getaddrinfo() \tOK\n");
        return getfd;
    }
}

int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res ){
    int sockfd = socket((*res)->ai_family, (*res)->ai_socktype, (*res)->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1 ){
        printf("Error, socket()\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else{
        printf("socket() \tOK\n");
        return sockfd;
    }
}

int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd ){
    int bindfd = bind(*sockfd, (*res)->ai_addr, (*res)->ai_addrlen);
    if (bindfd == -1 ){
        printf("Error, bind(), check line 34\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else{
        printf("bind() \t\tOK\n");
        return bindfd;
    }
}

int accept_fd(  struct sockaddr_storage *their_addr, int *sockfd  ){
    int new_fd;
    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof( *their_addr );
    new_fd = accept(*sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)their_addr, &addr_size);
    if (new_fd == -1 ){
        printf("Error, accept()\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else{
        printf("accept() \tOK\n");
        return new_fd;
    }
}

int list_fd( int *sockfd ){
    int listfd = listen(*sockfd, BACKLOG);
    if (listfd == -1 ){
        printf("Error, listen()\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else{
        printf("listen() \tOK\n");
        return listfd;
    }
}

ssize_t write_fd( const char *const msg, int *new_fd ){
    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    ssize_t wrtfd;
    wrtfd = write(*new_fd, msg, len );
    if (wrtfd == -1 ){
        printf("Error, write()\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }else{
        printf("write() \tOK\n");
    }

    return wrtfd;
}
```

Compiler flags:

```
-Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c17 -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wold-style-definition -Wconversion -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-align=strict -Wformat -O0 -g
```

Output:

> ```
> program.c:14:22: error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
>  int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res );
>                       ^~~~~~~~
> program.c:15:23: error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
>  int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res );
>                        ^~~~~~~~
> program.c:18:21: error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
>  int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd );
>                      ^~~~~~~~
> program.c: In function ‘main’:
> program.c:24:21: error: storage size of ‘server’ isn’t known
>      struct addrinfo server, *res;
>                      ^~~~~~
> program.c:28:16: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
>      getAdr_fd( server, &res );
>                 ^~~~~~
> program.c:28:24: error: passing argument 2 of ‘getAdr_fd’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
>      getAdr_fd( server, &res );
>                         ^~~~
> program.c:14:57: note: expected ‘struct addrinfo **’ but argument is of type ‘struct addrinfo **’
>  int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res );
>                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
> program.c:29:25: error: passing argument 1 of ‘create_fd’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
>      sockfd = create_fd( &res );
>                          ^~~~
> program.c:15:34: note: expected ‘struct addrinfo **’ but argument is of type ‘struct addrinfo **’
>  int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res );
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
> program.c:32:14: error: passing argument 1 of ‘bind_fd’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
>      bind_fd( &res, &sockfd );
>               ^~~~
> program.c:18:32: note: expected ‘struct addrinfo **’ but argument is of type ‘struct addrinfo **’
>  int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd );
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
> program.c:45:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeaddrinfo’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>      freeaddrinfo(res);
>      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
> program.c:24:21: error: unused variable ‘server’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
>      struct addrinfo server, *res;
>                      ^~~~~~
> program.c: At top level:
> program.c:48:23: error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
>   int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res ){
>                        ^~~~~~~~
> program.c:48:32: error: parameter 1 (‘server’) has incomplete type
>   int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res ){
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
> program.c: In function ‘getAdr_fd’:
> program.c:56:23: error: ‘AI_PASSIVE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘AF_WANPIPE’?
>      server.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // fill in my IP for me
>                        ^~~~~~~~~~
>                        AF_WANPIPE
> program.c:56:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
> program.c:58:13: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getaddrinfo’; did you mean ‘getAdr_fd’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>      getfd = getaddrinfo( NULL, PORT, &server, res);
>              ^~~~~~~~~~~
>              getAdr_fd
> program.c:60:46: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gai_strerror’; did you mean ‘strerror’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>          fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror( getfd ));
>                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
>                                               strerror
> program.c:60:40: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format=]
>          fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror( getfd ));
>                                        ~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>                                        %d
> program.c:48:32: error: unused parameter ‘server’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
>   int getAdr_fd(struct addrinfo server, struct addrinfo **res ){
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
> program.c: At top level:
> program.c:68:23: error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
>  int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res ){
>                        ^~~~~~~~
> program.c:68:5: error: conflicting types for ‘create_fd’
>  int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res ){
>      ^~~~~~~~~
> program.c:15:5: note: previous declaration of ‘create_fd’ was here
>  int create_fd( struct addrinfo **res );
>      ^~~~~~~~~
> program.c: In function ‘create_fd’:
> program.c:69:31: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct addrinfo’
>      int sockfd = socket((*res)->ai_family, (*res)->ai_socktype, (*res)->ai_protocol);
>                                ^~
> program.c: At top level:
> program.c:79:21: error: ‘struct addrinfo’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
>  int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd ){
>                      ^~~~~~~~
> program.c:79:5: error: conflicting types for ‘bind_fd’
>  int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd ){
>      ^~~~~~~
> program.c:18:5: note: previous declaration of ‘bind_fd’ was here
>  int bind_fd( struct addrinfo **res, int *sockfd );
>      ^~~~~~~
> program.c: In function ‘bind_fd’:
> program.c:80:38: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct addrinfo’
>      int bindfd = bind(*sockfd, (*res)->ai_addr, (*res)->ai_addrlen);
>                                       ^~
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Another strange thing which I notice is:

```
program.c:45:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeaddrinfo’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 freeaddrinfo(res);
```

But the include files are there:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.
```

Linux Mint 19, GCC-8.0.1.

Comment: The mode you're using doesn't automatically define the appropriate feature test macro to get `getadddrinfo()` and friends declared. See the man page for details.

Comment: @Shawn The mode I am using? Which is than the right way, because I just can't figure out.

Comment: `Since glibc 2.22: _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L, Glibc 2.21 and earlier: _POSIX_C_SOURCE`

Comment: C11, C17, etc. That mode. You already mention one right way in your post. You can also define one of the needed feature test macros before including any headers if you don't want to change the language standard mode from a plain one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This borders on a glibc bug.  While it is true that `struct addrinfo` is not part of the C standard, neither is `<netdb.h>`, so it would not do any harm to define it in that header (except for very old POSIX versions).

You can still specify any of the C standard options and get the GNU extensions if you compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`.  See the glibc documentation and the manual page:

- [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)
- [Feature test macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

Comment: So there is no `#include` that will allow this to work when compiling with `-std=c17`?

Answer (score 3):

The `getaddrinfo` function, and by extension the `struct addrinfo` type, are specified by POSIX.  This means that they're not part of the C standard.

So when you specify `-std=c99`, `-std=c11` or `-std=c17`, it excludes those types because they are not specified by the standard.  Specifying a `-std=gnuxx` option includes the definitions of those types.